# Android interstitial admob causes a lot of GC_FOR_ALLOC freed messages in logcat

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob, interstitial

I'm developing a simple game with libgdx. I faced with unpleasant issue during integration of AdMob interstitial ad. Here is a code which loads ad in onCreate method of AndroidApplication:

```
interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getApplication());
interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID);
AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
AdRequest ad = builder.build();
try { 
   interstitialAd.loadAd(ad);
}
catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So once "interstitialAd.loadAd(ad);" is happened my game starts to lag and logcat shows big bunch of "GC_FOR_ALLOC freed" messages:

```
08-29 13:39:14.965  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1029K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 59ms, total 59ms
08-29 13:39:14.965  29994-29994/com.a1.runner.android D/WebView﹕ loadUrlImpl: called
08-29 13:39:14.995  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1029K, 18% free 15493K/18880K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-29 13:39:14.995  29994-30245/com.a1.runner.android D/webcore﹕ CORE loadUrl: called
08-29 13:39:14.995  29994-30245/com.a1.runner.android D/webkit﹕ Firewall not null
08-29 13:39:14.995  29994-30245/com.a1.runner.android D/webkit﹕ euler: isUrlBlocked = false
08-29 13:39:15.030  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1028K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-29 13:39:15.060  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-29 13:39:15.095  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-29 13:39:15.125  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-29 13:39:15.155  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-29 13:39:15.185  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
08-29 13:39:16.290  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 60ms, total 60ms
08-29 13:39:16.295  29994-29994/com.a1.runner.android D/WebView﹕ loadUrlImpl: called
08-29 13:39:16.330  29994-30245/com.a1.runner.android D/webcore﹕ CORE loadUrl: called
08-29 13:39:16.330  29994-30245/com.a1.runner.android D/webkit﹕ Firewall not null
08-29 13:39:16.330  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1030K, 18% free 15494K/18880K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
08-29 13:39:16.330  29994-30245/com.a1.runner.android D/webkit﹕ euler: isUrlBlocked = false
08-29 13:39:16.365  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1027K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
08-29 13:39:16.395  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-29 13:39:16.425  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-29 13:39:16.455  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-29 13:39:16.490  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
08-29 13:39:16.520  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-29 13:39:17.600  29994-29994/com.a1.runner.android D/WebView﹕ loadUrlImpl: called
08-29 13:39:17.600  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1029K, 18% free 15493K/18880K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
08-29 13:39:17.600  29994-30245/com.a1.runner.android D/webcore﹕ CORE loadUrl: called
08-29 13:39:17.600  29994-30245/com.a1.runner.android D/webkit﹕ Firewall not null
08-29 13:39:17.600  29994-30245/com.a1.runner.android D/webkit﹕ euler: isUrlBlocked = false
08-29 13:39:17.635  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1028K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-29 13:39:17.665  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-29 13:39:17.695  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-29 13:39:17.730  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 29ms, total 30ms
08-29 13:39:17.760  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-29 13:39:17.790  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
08-29 13:39:17.820  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
08-29 13:39:19.060  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 62ms, total 62ms
08-29 13:39:19.090  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 18% free 15491K/18880K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
08-29 13:39:19.095  29994-29994/com.a1.runner.android D/WebView﹕ loadUrlImpl: called
08-29 13:39:19.125  29994-30245/com.a1.runner.android D/webcore﹕ CORE loadUrl: called
08-29 13:39:19.125  29994-32552/com.a1.runner.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1029K, 18% free 15493K/18880K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
```

After several seconds these messages stop to appear and the game starts to play smoothly. If to comment "interstitialAd.loadAd(ad);" then the game goes smoothly as well. I use com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.3.0

**UPD.** Noticed that this is happened with ads which contains video.

Comment: Are you showing the ad onLoad()? If so, you shouldn't.

Comment: I don't show it. It's only loaded in "onCreate" method.

Comment: Try changing, on this line: `interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getApplication());`
the method "getApplication()" to "getApplicationContext()", or "this" or "getContext()", see if any of these works.

Comment: No, this doesn't help.